# How to change the footer link iin Magento?

Tags: magento-1.8

[image]    How to customize the footer links in below showed theme.

I want to remove the Store Locater which is shown in the footer,how to change the footer links.

Comment: There is no below showed theme

Comment: Why is there no debug path box around the menu? Have you hard coded it in the main template file?

Comment: @arunaangadi You need to check CMS block in admin panel